# How do I change the conversion of the hex string to byte array to avoid unintentional image thresholding?

Tags: c#, image

This is a follow-up to this question: [How to convert an SQL Server BLOB string to System.Drawing.Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082167/how-to-convert-an-sql-server-blob-string-to-system-drawing-image)

#### Background

I am going to import information about users together with their photo from a csv file using c#. The proprietary SDK that I use requires the photo to be a System.Drawing.Image

Below is an example of the csv file:

```
surname firstname   photo                       
Blogs    Joe        0xFFD8FFE000104A46494600010101005F005F0000FFDB0043000D090A
```

I use the code found in the answer to my previous question ([How to convert an SQL Server BLOB string to System.Drawing.Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082167/how-to-convert-an-sql-server-blob-string-to-system-drawing-image)) to convert the BLOB that is represented by a hex string into a byte array and then subsequently into a System.Drawing.Image.

This is the code (from my previous question) that I use to convert from a hex string of a BLOB into a byte array. This principle works.

```
  strPhoto = csvuser.photo; // The string that represents the BLOB

  //remove first 2 chars (the '0x')
  strPhoto = strPhoto.Remove(0, 2);

  //convert hex-string to bytes:
  int NumberChars = strPhoto.Length/2;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars];
  using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(strPhoto)){
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i++)
           bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2]{(char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read()}), 16);
  }

  // Then we create a memory stream that holds the image
  MemoryStream photostream = new MemoryStream( bytes );

  // Then we can create a System.Drawing.Image by using the Memory stream
  var photo = Image.FromStream(photostream);
```

**However, some higher resolution images are thresholed so that the bottom half of the photo is black with some predictable patterns of white dots whilst the upper half is as intended.**

The photos that import correctly are

```
>=640x480
```

and the ones that don't are

```
<640x480
```

in size. All with bit depth 24. This is something I have observed but not sure if that is relevant. The original images are 24 bit and it seems to me that  the conversion to a byte array creates a lower bit "image" and therefore half of the photo is black with a predictable patterns of white dots.

#### Question

How do I change the conversion of the hex string to byte array to avoid the unintentional thresholding?

Comment: Most likely the loss of quality you are seeing is happening when the image is being encoded for storage in to the database, NOT when you convert from Hex > byte > image.  How are the images getting in to the database?  I'd be willing to bet that this is where the problem actually lies.

Comment: The photos are taken through a capture toolthat belongs to a commercial system. That system consists of two parts. One capture tool and one viewing tool where you can view the details of a person including view the photo. All Photos look as they should with the viewing tool so I am a bit puzzled.